# Is it possible to make a link with rounded corners in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, webkit

I've searched seemingly everywhere, and tried multiple approaches but can't find a solution to this basic issue. Making a link fit inside of a box with rounded corners without overflowing. The example works fine in Firefox which bothers me even more.

Edit: Below Passerby made this excellent example to better visualize the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/wjpdd/7/

The best work-around I've found for this issue is making the div clickable with javascript and styling the :hover cursor in css. but would love a less boot-legged option if anyone has one

Original example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wjpdd/3/

and the 
html:

```
    <div class="circle">
      <a href="#" class="fill">
        <div class="circleoutline">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.circle{
    width: 310px;
    height: 310px;
    border-radius: 155px;
    background-color: grey;
    top: 18px;
    left: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.fill{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 155px;
}

.circleoutline{
    position: relative;
    top:5.5px;
    left:5.5px;
    width: 295px;
    height: 295px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius:150px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: It works for me in Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/xZ5Iy.png

Comment: @Blender it looks good, but on mouse-over the link extends outside the boundaries of the circle, at least on my set-up.

Comment: Works fine for me too. Even mousing over.

Comment: @Jess I understand your problem. I agree that this can be annoying to someone. Here I made you a fiddle that may demonstrate your problem more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/wjpdd/7/

Comment: @Passerby thanks for that I'll add it to the top post, I wonder if this is something that can be solved in css/html or a glitch in chrome/webkit.

Comment: @JeffreyRay and you're in chrome on windows? strange. I've definitely been able to re-create the issue on multiple computers

Comment: Ive just tried it in FF + IE9, windows 8 and everything works just fine.

Comment: It's known bug of chrome -> [https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71639](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71639)

Comment: @Morpheus I think this is different because it happens regardless of whether the parent div is positioned relative or absolute

Comment: @MickJones I did some more testing and it seems to only work as expected in Firefox/IE